# Why don't I need to overload the = operator?

Tags: c++, struct, overloading

I've made a simple test program:

```
struct Mystruct{
  int x = 1, y = 2
};
int main(){
  myStruct test1;
  myStruct test2;
  test1.x = 2;
  test1.y = 2;
  test2 = test1;
}
```

Why does this work? How can `test2` successfully get the values of `x` and `y` put into its `x` and `y`? In my experience I would need to overload the `=` operator for the struct but it seems I don't. need to in this case.

Comment: could you direct me to the duplicate?

Comment: The link is shown *above* the question (for some reason). Also, the short answer is that you have always been able to assign structs in C, so C++ just kept that rule (for structs that could have been declared in C).